# How to add if statement in the map function using react

Tags: reactjs

Hi guys I'm trying to filter out the first iteration of the map function because its undefined and I don't want it to show,

the code is this:

```
  const data = this.state.arr.map((r, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <th>{index}</th>
        <th>{r.formName}</th>
        <th>{this.state.numofSub} </th>
        <th>
          <Link to={`/submitPage/${r._id}`}>Submit PageLink</Link>
        </th>
        <th>
          <Link to={`/submissionPage/${r._id}`}>Submission page Link </Link>
        </th>
      </tr>
    ));
```

I tried adding if statement before the render like so:

```
  const data = this.state.arr.map((r, index) => (
  if(r._id){
      <tr key={index}>
        <th>{index}</th>
        <th>{r.formName}</th>
        <th>{this.state.numofSub} </th>
        <th>
          <Link to={`/submitPage/${r._id}`}>Submit PageLink</Link>
        </th>
        <th>
          <Link to={`/submissionPage/${r._id}`}>Submission page Link </Link>
        </th>
      </tr>
    )}
else return NULL
);
```

but it won't compile, can someone tell me how is the proper way to do this?
to be clear I just want to check that the r._id has something in it, if it doesn't then I don't want it to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `map` function doesn't have a body (curly braces) `{}`.
And you forgot a return after the `if` statement.

```
 const data = this.state.arr.map((r, index) => {
  if(r._id){
    return(
      <tr key={index}>
        <th>{index}</th>
        <th>{r.formName}</th>
        <th>{this.state.numofSub} </th>
        <th>
          <Link to={`/submitPage/${r._id}`}>Submit PageLink</Link>
        </th>
        <th>
          <Link to={`/submissionPage/${r._id}`}>Submission page Link </Link>
        </th>
      </tr>
    )
   }
    else return null
})
```

**Note** that this will return an array with null in it. If you need to filter then chain [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before the `map`

Comment: this code wont compile, I even tried copying and same error.

Comment: @AlexAlex i had a missing closing `)` in the end.  Edited

Comment: { brackets are not mandatory. map works even with (. return is required when we use { brackets and return isn't required when we use ( bracket

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator and render JSX elements directly in render using .map

```
render(){
 const { arr, numofSub } = this.state;
 return(
    {arr && arr.map((r, index) => (
      {r._id ? (
      <tr key={`${r.formName}-${index}`}>
       <th>{index}</th>
       <th>{r.formName}</th>
       <th>{numofSub} </th>
       <th>
        <Link to={`/submitPage/${r._id}`}>Submit PageLink</Link>
      </th>
      <th>
         <Link to={`/submissionPage/${r._id}`}>Submission page Link </Link>
      </th>
    </tr>) : null}
))})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Array.prototype.filter() method is quite effective to resolve issues like this. Something like this:

```
const filteredData = this.state.arr.filter(item => item.id !== undefined)
const data = filteredData.map((r, index) => (
  ...
)
```

No if statement needed with this setup.